# using apply_visitor to filter from vector of variant

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant, apply-visitor

Yesterday I asked this question and "juanchopanza" answered my question, but unfortunately I cant caught one of bounded types. Since using a "visitor" is more robust, I'm also wondering of anyone could give me a solution using "visitor"?

I am looking for the best way to filter a vector of the boost variant which has been defined like this:

```
 boost::variant<T1*, T2, T3> Var;
 std::vector<Var> Vec;
```

when I call this vector, what is the best way to filter only T2 bounded type and insert into new vector? or in other way, I want something like this

`std::vector<T2> T2Vec =` ...(how to filter it from Vec using **apply_visitor**)...

thanks again!

EDIT:
the sulotion by @ ForEveR:

```
template<typename T>
struct T_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
   T_visitor(std::vector<T>& v) : vec(v) {}
   template<typename U>
   void operator () (const U&) {}
   void operator () (const T& value)
   {
      vec.push_back(value);
   }
private:
   std::vector<T>& vec;
};
```

and:

```
  std::vector<T1> t1vec;
  T_visitor<T1> vis(t1vec);
  std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), boost::apply_visitor(vis));
```

would you please tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: `T_visitor vis(t1vec);` You're missing template arguments here.

Comment: @juanchopanza for these visitor, How can I change it in such way that the new vector contain the address of objects in the memory, or vector of pointers point to these objects?

Comment: You can use an `std::vector<T1*>` and then `vec.push_back(&value)`, but beware: vector re-allocations can make pointers or iterators to the vector's elements invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
struct T2_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
   T2_visitor(std::vector<T2>& v) : vec(v) {}
   template<typename T>
   void operator () (const T&) {}
   void operator () (const T2& value)
   {
      vec.push_back(value);
   }
private:
   std::vector<T2>& vec;
};

std::vector<T2> T2Vec;
T2_visitor vis(T2Vec);
std::for_each(Vec.begin(), Vec.end(), boost::apply_visitor(vis));
```

Comment: thanks @ ForEveR, is it possible to expand such that any bounded types (T1*, T2 and T3) would be applicable for "T2_visitor"? in other word make it as T_visitor?

Comment: @H'H why not? overload operators for all types and use 3 vectors... or make visitor templated, something like this http://ideone.com/JjeorN can help

Comment: @ ForEver, when I applied I received the following errors: /home/m.cc:1027:13: error: missing template arguments before ‘vis’
/home/m.cc:1027:13: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘vis’
/home/m.cc:1028:68: error: ‘vis’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @H'H of course... T_visitor should be constructed with template parameter.

Comment: @H'H It should be `T_visitor<T1> vis(t1vec);`